# Angular Component inheritance not updating the base component

Tags: angular, typescript

[example on browser for debug](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-inheritance-notupdatingbase?file=src%2Fapp%2Finherited%2Finherited.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Finherited%2Finherited.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

base component

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-base-component',
  template: `<p>
  <b>base</b> component counter: {{ counter }} --
  <b>should have been updated</b>
</p>
<ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>`,
  styleUrls: ['base.component.css'],
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public counter = 0;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

inheritance

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inherited-component',
  template: `<app-base-component>
  <ng-container body>
    <p><b>inherited</b> component counter: {{ counter }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</app-base-component>`,
  styleUrls: ['inherited.component.css'],
})
export class InheritedComponent extends BaseComponent {
  public ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

app component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<app-inherited-component [counter]="20"></app-inherited-component>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'everyone';
}
```

for some reason, my base counter is 0. I want this to be 20.

[image]

Comment: `<app-inherited-component [counter]="20">` but `InheritedComponent` has no `@Input()` decorators. Your inherited component should receive `counter` and then it passes it to the `BaseComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `InheritedComponent` you also create a new `<app-base-component>` inside the View. With `ng-container` you access the counter of the `BaseComponent` which you did not initialize. You simply need to do:

```html
<app-base-component [counter]="counter">
  <ng-container body>
    <p><b>inherited</b> component counter: {{ counter }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</app-base-component>
```

But you can acces the `counter` directly from the inherited component simply by:

```html
{{ counter }}
```